# Create a Terraform data for an s3 bucket that uses bucket_prefix

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have multiple Terraform projects, in project A I create a bucket like this:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3_bucket" {
  bucket_prefix = "s3-bucket-"
}
```

this create a bucket with a random characters in the ends:

```
s3-bucket-20230927170795326300000001
```

Now I want to refer the name of this bucket in another project B, so I create:

```
data "aws_s3_bucket" "s3_bucket" {
  bucket = "s3-bucket-"
}
```

But this will not work because the name is random, is there any trick to solve this?

Comment: To clarify: is each "Terraform project" a separate root module, or are they two declared modules within the same root module, or is one a declared module within the other root module?

Comment: @MatthewSchuchard they are two separate modules with two different states

Comment: Two separate root modules in this situation would require an output from the first mapped to an input variable in the second. How that would occur depends on your environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store the bucket name in SSM Parameter Store (or Secrets Manager, if you prefer; however, SSM is more cost-effective, and I assume that this data is not highly security-sensitive).

Here’s an example:

```js
resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "bucket-prod" {
  name  = "/bucket-names/prod"
  type  = "String"
  value = var.bucket-name
}
```

Afterwards, you can retrieve it in another module:

```js
data "aws_ssm_parameter" "bucket-prod" {
  name = "/bucket-names/prod"
}

data "aws_s3_bucket" "s3_bucket" {
  bucket = data.aws_ssm_parameter.bucket-prod.value
}
```

You can also find more info on how to use SSM resources in the official Terraform docs [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ssm_parameter).

Comment: I like this solution

Answer (score 0):

You can try importing the bucket into project B:

```
terraform import 'aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket' your-new-bucket-name
```

https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/import

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer, It is really bad to manipulate states like this, so this solution is not in my scope at all. beside check this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77188651/create-a-terraform-data-for-an-s3-bucket-that-uses-bucket-prefix#comment136076715_77188709

Comment: @Doesn'tMatter why do you say this. This is the recommended pattern to import existing resources into a terraform configuration and all terraform resources generally provide the import command for the resource in their docs. It would only be considered bad if you were actually editing the state file directly.

Answer (score 0):

One quick trick is NOT to use that random stuff, you could append something unique like the aws account id

```
data "aws_caller_identity" "current" {}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3_bucket" {
  bucket = "test-bucket-${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}"
}
```

then you can use the same in the data

```
data "aws_caller_identity" "current" {}

data "aws_s3_bucket" "s3_bucket" {
  bucket = "test-bucket-${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}"
}
```